# Where is the marriage of F. M. Weston/Mason to a Goodman?

Tags: england, marriage-records, london, 1930s

My 2x Great Grandmother was Milly Bungay(Bungay/Bungy/Bungey/Mason/Weston). She was born 28th August 1860 in Romsey, Hampshire, England. She died in 1947 which has been recently verified using the 1939 Register + Death Certificate (See sources) as she is living with her daughter Eleanor Kate Carter (nee Mason).

I have a few questions so I will be splitting this post into three sections, the others can be found here:

- [Where is the 1911 Census record relating to Milly Bungay/Mason/Weston?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10126/where-is-the-1911-census-record-relating-to-milly-bungay-mason-weston)
- [Where is the Marriage of Milly Bungay/Mason/Weston to John Weston?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10123/where-is-the-marriage-of-milly-bungay-mason-weston-to-john-weston)

---

On Milly's death certificate the 'informant' is listed as 'F. M. Goodman, Daughter, 35 Belton Road, Willesden'. I can't find any record of a Weston to a Goodman.

[image]

**My Question is:** Can anyone find a record of Marriage between one of Milly's daughters with the initials 'F.M.' and a 'Goodman'?

---

**Sources:**

My Ancestry.co.uk tree for Milly Bungay:
http://person.ancestry.co.uk/tree/72266092/person/34262238127

Marriage Certificate for Milly Bungay and Robert Mason (1883):
[image: Milly Marriage Certificate]

[1891 Census:](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QNFZ-SPZ)
[image]

[1901 Census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:X96D-B4S):
[image]

1911 Census - missing! See [Where is the 1911 Census record relating to Milly Bungay/Mason/Weston?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10126/where-is-the-1911-census-record-relating-to-milly-bungay-mason-weston)

1939 Register:
[image: Milly Weston - 1939 Register]

Death Certificate for Milly Weston (1947):
[image]

Comment: I just cleaned up some of the sources and removed the ones that pertained to before Milly's marriage, since this post is about her daughter. Feel free to roll back if you would rather the earlier censuses were included here too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1946 Electoral Register for 35 Belton Rd, Willesdon, shows the following individuals:

- Burt, Eva
- Burt, William C.
- Goodman, Florence M.
- Weston, Percy E.

Florence and various other family members were at this address through the 1960s; it is worth checking every year's electoral roll.

This suggests that the daughter who was the informant was Florence May Goodman (nee Weston), born c.1897:

```
Births Jun qtr 1897
Weston  Florence May    Hendon  3a  181
```

As you know, Florence (Mason) appears age 4 on the 1901 census with Milly. She is probably with Milly in 1911 though that record still needs to be found, if it exists.

The [1939 Register Index](http://search.findmypast.com/results/world-records/1939-register?firstname=florence%20m&firstname_variants=true&lastname=goodman&registrationdistrict=willesden%20m.b.) shows a Arthur J. Goodman and Florence M. Goodman living together in Willesden. The image would have to be purchased for full information, however from the index it is possible to obtain the following information:

1939 Register index:

```
Arthur J Goodman    1890    Willesden M.B.  Middlesex
Florence M Goodman  1897    Willesden M.B.  Middlesex
Arthur Goodman      1934    Willesden M.B.  Middlesex
+1 more person officially closed
```

In the GRO birth index there are the following entries:

```
Births Jun qtr 1934
Goodman     Arthur J.   mms Weston  Willesden   3a  540
Weston      Arthur J.   mms Weston  Willesden   3a  540
```

The fact that this birth is indexed under both the father's surname and mother's maiden surname suggests that the child was illegitimate.

Also, as Arthur J. Goodman (Jr.) appears in the 1939 Register index, he is presumably deceased. Looking at the GRO death index, there is a likely death for him in 1952, in Willesden, age 17.

There is another son, birth registered in Mar qtr 1937, registered only under the surname Goodman. This is likely the closed person on the 1939 Register index. This son (and his wife) appear on the electoral registers with Florence in the 1960s, still at the address of 35 Belton Rd, Willesden.

Arthur J. Goodman died in 1945 in Willesden, explaining why Florence's husband is not on the electoral register with her in 1946.

Looking at earlier electoral registered, the following individuals are recorded on the 1935-36 electoral registers at 24 Essex Rd, Willesden:

- Goodman, Arthur James
- Weston, Florence May
- +others likely unrelated

Arthur is at that address on the 1934 electoral register, but Florence is not recorded with him.

Arthur and Florence are at that address on the 1937 electoral register, but now Florence's surname is now Goodman.

All this would seem to suggest a marriage in about 1936, though I have been unable to locate one.

Comment: Thank you!, The Burt surnames match up with her daughter Eva Emily's family. The marriage record still eludes me...

Comment: @Danny As an aside, I don't think it's Eva Emily - every record I could find, including her birth record, just says Eva. On your tree you have linked a birth in Ricmond RD, but she was born in Hendon RD. ;)

Comment: Just looked at her Baptism... Not sure where I got Eva Emily from either... Better take out that birth record and add the actual one