# Where is the 1911 Census record relating to Milly Bungay/Mason/Weston?

Tags: england, census-records, london, 1910s

My 2x Great Grandmother was Milly Bungay(Bungay/Bungy/Bungey/Mason/Weston). She was born 28th August 1860 in Romsey, Hampshire, England. She died in 1945 which has been recently verified using the 1939 Register + Death Certificate(See sources) as she is living with her daughter Eleanor Kate Carter(nee Mason).

I have a few questions so I will be splitting this post into three sections, the others can be found here:

- [Where is the Marriage of Milly Bungay/Mason/Weston to John Weston?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10123/where-is-the-marriage-of-milly-bungay-mason-weston-to-john-weston)
- [Where is the marriage of F. M. Weston/Mason to a Goodman?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10125/where-is-the-marriage-of-f-m-weston-mason-to-a-goodman)

I can't seem to locate a 1911 Census, which will be important in the other two questions.

**My Question is:** Can anyone find a 1911 Census record for Milly?

**Sources:**

My Ancestry.co.uk tree for Milly Bungay: http://person.ancestry.co.uk/tree/72266092/person/34262238127

[image]
https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:X96D-B4S - 1901 Census (Willesden, Middlesex)

[image]
https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QNFZ-SPZ - 1891 Census

[image]
https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:QK6R-JXGG - 1881 Census (Islington, London, Middlesex)

[image]
https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VFDY-J41 - 1871 Census

[image]

I can't find the 1861 Census on familysearch but above is a picture. The citation is: *Class: RG 9; Piece: 685; Folio: 24; Page: 12; GSU roll: 542684*

[image: Milly Weston - 1939 Register]

Milly Weston - 1939 Register shown above.

[image: Milly Weston Death Certificate]

Milly Weston - Marriage Certificate shown above.

[image]

Milly Weston - Death Certificate shown above.

Answer (score 2):

I've found John Weston on the 1911 census - parish of Bentley with Arksey near Doncaster - his birthplace recorded as Birchclere Hants which matches other records. Can't see Milly so far. Hope this info may help eliminate some avenues.